# Does String.split(" ") in Java do all the work up front?

Tags: java, string

Say I have a very long String called `str`, and I'm looking for the first instance of `"hello"`. For now we can say each token is separated by a space, but in the more complex case it won't be, hence the use of split rather than StringTokenizer. 
Now, let's also say `"hello"` is only the third word in the String. Is the following algorithm `O(n)` or `O(1)`?

```
for (String word : str.split(" ") )
    if ( word.equals("hello") ) return;
```

Comment: Answer to your question is `O(n)` because if the word you are looking for is the last one or nonexistent all words have to be looked at, so linear time.

Comment: @jlordo Sorry, yes, have corrected to .split(" ")

Comment: what's ´n´, number of words or number of chars in the original string?

Comment: There is no such thing as `array.split()` in Java, and it isn't what your question is about.

Comment: @jlordo Re your answer: What I was trying to figure out is if "hello" is KNOWN to be the third word, does the compiler still split the entire string, or does it just traverse through the String as required?

Comment: The compiler sees `str.split(" ")` and does not care what you will do with the resulting array, so it will absolutely split the whole string (because thats how the `split` method is implemented. If you know the number of tokens you want, you can use `split(String regex, int limit)`, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int))

Comment: split will split the entire String. Then the array is passed to the for-each loop.

Comment: Understood. So if I am searching for the existence of `"hello"` in order to get it down to O(k), where `"hello"` is the kth word, I'd have to implement something myself, is that right?

Answer (score 3):

It would be `O(1)` if it does not matter how many tokens you have in your array, which is not true. It is `O(n)`.

Comment: O(1) would mean that there are no time increasing parameters. But there are. The number of tokens/words influence the performance linear